# Заполнить ObservableCollection в зависимости от выбранного значения в ComboBox wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

У меня есть Combobox который заполняется из коллекции

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding clients, IsAsync=True}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"
                          x:Name="Client"/>
```

И есть другая коллекция, которая должна заполняться в зависимости от выбранного значения в ComboBox.
Пробую заполнять так:

```
protected Client mSelected;
    public Client Selected 
    {
        get => mSelected;
        set
        {
            if (mSelected == null)
                return;
            mSelected = value;
            if (Selected != null)
            {
                Search();
            }
        }
    }
public List<GroupModel> groupModels { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Client> clients { get; set; }

public void Search()
    {
        FilteredItems = new List<GroupModel>(Filter(Selected.Name));
    }


    public IEnumerable<GroupModel> Filter(string path)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clients[i].Name == path)
            {
                groupModels = new List<GroupModel>(GetInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(clients[i].paths[i].DefaultFolder)));
            }
        }

        return groupModels;
    }

        public IEnumerable<GroupModel> GetInfo(string path)
    {
        groupModels = new List<GroupModel>();

        foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            GroupModel group = new GroupModel()
            {
                Name = new FileInfo(item).Name.Substring(new FileInfo(item).Name.Length - 4),
                items = new List<DecreeModel>(GetDecree(item)),
                IsChecked = false
            };
            CountReg++;
            groupModels.Add(group);
        }
        return groupModels;
    }
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Событие, которое вызывается, когда какое-либо дочернее свойство меняет свое значение.
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    // Необходимо, чтобы вызвать событие <see cref = "PropertyChanged" />
    public void OnPropertyChanget( string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Подправил Selected

```
protected Client mSelected;
    public Client Selected 
    {
        get => mSelected;
        set
        {
            mSelected = value;
            if (mSelected != null)
            {
                Search();
            }
            OnPropertyChanget(nameof(Selected));
        }
    }
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Что не получается?

Comment: alladuh, ничего не происходит. Выбираю в combobox, а коллекция не заполняется и не отображается.

Comment: Я к тому, что не особо понятно из описания, что должно произойти. У вас есть список и коллекция, потом откуда-то в методе ``Search`` появляется ``FilteredItems ``

Comment: alladuh, FilteredItems это тоже список и ему присваивается другой list. Может он и лишний. Я читаю папку на компе и заношу в список, потом этот список биндится к ItemsControl. Так вот мне необходимо, чтобы при выборе из Combobox подставлялся другой путь к паке и заносился в список и отобразился в ItemControl

Comment: А вы когда под дебагом смотрите, список заполняется?

Comment: alladuh, попробовал через дебаг, получается этот метод не срабатывает. Может в Selected что-не правильно

Comment: Вы попробуйте пройти он начала метода Search и далее и увидите, где он перестаёт работать. Отсюда может станет яснее почему.
Может такой файл не находится или путь к директории неверный

Comment: Я так понимаю привязка идет к `public List<GroupModel> groupModels { get; set; }`? Если так, то где INPC?

Comment: Показывает, что Selected пустая. Не получается в Selected отправить путь выбрав его в Combobox.

Comment: EvgeniyZ, класс уже наследует INPC. INPC в отдельном классе.

Comment: public class DecreeViewModel : BaseViewModel

Comment: Наследует - не значит, что свойство его использует. Если `groupModels` используется в интерфейсе, то этих изменений вы не увидите там. А по поводу `Selected` - зачем вам там `if (mSelected == null)`? Изначально `mSelected` у вас NULL, а значит это условие будет всегда `true`. P.S. Обращайтесь к человеку через @ ибо без этого он не видит оповещений

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, изначально у меня в comboBox все выбиралось и подгружалось, но использовал SelectedIndex switch case, но это получается были статические данные. Сейчас же данные в Combobox будут добавляться

Comment: Мне это не о чем не говорит.

Comment: Не хватает кода, чтобы дать правильный ответ. Реализуйсте для всех свойств, к которым есть привязанные биндинги, вызов `OnPropertyChanged()` при их изменении. Так как вы сделали для `Selected`.

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся. Все сделал. Все работает.